# Return All Users Nested Data in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I have my firebase data structured as follow...

```
test-db
     - users
          - c6fadsfjdaflasdjflkadsjflasdjf
                 - books
                      - g6734fdfadfadsfadfadsfadfdasfdaf
                               - title: 'Hi'
                               - genre: 'There'
          - r78asdf8asdfdsaf87fdafadsf85fd
                 - books
                      - y664uu66df6dfdaff3sfdadfafhlklkl
                               - title: 'Thanks'
                               - genre: 'For Help'
```

How can I fetch an object of books which ALL the users have? as such...

```
{
  {
     title: 'Hi',
     genre: 'There'
   },
   {
     title: 'Thanks',
     genre: 'For Help'
   }
}
```

My current action creator is as below but it returns an object with separate objects under different users. I need one single object which I can then iterate through using lodash (to convert to an array) to display in my FlatList

My Current Action Creator which returns wrong results...

```
export const fetchAllBooks = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        try {
            firebase.database().ref(`/users`)
                .on('value', snapshot => {
                    snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
                        var childData = childSnapshot.val()
                        console.log('ChildData', childData)

                    })
                })
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('fetchAllBooks Error', error)
        }
    }
}
```

Appreciate help, thanks

Comment: Consider re-structure your database following this guideline https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data

Comment: Thanks. I ll look into it :)